# issues while converting ES query to java Code

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

i am trying to convert below ES query which is working in console to Java Code

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "ID.keyword": "1234457654"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {"match": {
                "stepName.keyword": "STEP1"
              }},
              {"match": {
                "stepName.keyword": "STEP2"
              }}
            ]
            
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Java code which i tried

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().
must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("ID.keyword", transformedDataDTO.getID()).operator(Operator.AND)).
should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("stepName.keyword", transformedDataDTO.getStepName()))
   .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("stepName.keyword", MigrationStatusEnum.getPreviousData(transformedDataDTO.getStepName())));
```

instead of returning data matching to step1 or step2 it returns all the data

Please suggest what is missing in above java code or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach since you're doing an exact match on `stepName.keyword`, why not using `terms` (which has implicit `OR` semantics), and your query simply becomes:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "ID.keyword": "1234457654"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "stepName.keyword": [
              "STEP1",
              "STEP2"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Translated to Java:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
   .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("ID.keyword", transformedDataDTO.getID()))
   .filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("stepName.keyword", transformedDataDTO.getStepName(), MigrationStatusEnum.getPreviousData(transformedDataDTO.getStepName())));
```